# Change colors of SVG after clicked on particular path on that SVG

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics

I have been developing a ticket booking application where in I need to show seating arrangements as shown in the image below[image when imported in android (vector asset]. I have an SVG file of that image.

What i want to do is when clicked on a particular seat it should change its color. In simple words something like click event. It would be very grateful if anyone could answer this or give some reference. Thanks.[image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhoAb.png)

Comment: so what can be done to achieve this? I mean any alternative means for dynamic seating positions? @pskink

Comment: can you suggest an example? @pskink

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to change the color of your imageview displaying svg (vector drawable):

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(seatIv,ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue)));
```